# [Python]Put names in alphabetical order

Tags: python

For this code i need a way for the user to be able to choose a way on how to arrange the code, so if the user inputs 'A' then the code will arrange with the names in alphabetical order. Most of this code is pretty simple, i just cant find anyway to have the code create random names while being in alphabetical order. I know im asking alot but it would be great if anyone could help out. (Its a table in python by the way, No custom stuff just pure python)

```
    from random import randint
import random
import math

print ('''

-----------------------
      Class 5A
-----------------------


------------------------------------''')
for i in range(10): #Class 5A
    name = ['John', 'David', 'Bob', 'Luke', 'James', 'Kyle', 'Sam', 'Adam', 'Rick', 'Charlie', 'Alan', 'George', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Batman', 'Oliver', 'Rebeca', 'Emily', 'Amy', 'Nat', 'Ellie', 'Maddie', 'Clidna', 'Tor', 'Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Olivia', 'Sam', 'Lynn',]
    surname = [' Dyde', ' Davis', ' Pennington', ' Kelly', ' Hadfield', ' Millward', ' Bennet', ' Goldrick', ' Webb', ' West', ' Cotton', ' Pie', ' Rasberry', ' Fujitsu', ' Neil', ' Gothem',]
    score1 = randint(1, 10)
    score2 = randint(1, 10)
    score3 = randint(1, 10)
    average1 = (score1 + score2 + score3)/3
    score1 = str(score1)
    score2 = str(score2)
    score3 = str(score3)
    average1 = round(average1)
    average1 = str(average1)
    print (('Name: ')+(random.choice(name))+(random.choice(surname)))
    print (('Class: 5A'))
    print (('Score1: ')+(score1))
    print (('Score2: ')+(score2))
    print (('Score3: ')+(score3))
    print (('Average Score: ')+(average1))
    print ('------------------------------------')

print ('''

-----------------------
      Class 5B
-----------------------


------------------------------------''')
for i in range(10): #Class 5B
    name = ['John', 'David', 'Bob', 'Luke', 'James', 'Kyle', 'Sam', 'Adam', 'Rick', 'Charlie', 'Alan', 'George', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Batman', 'Oliver', 'Rebeca', 'Emily', 'Amy', 'Nat', 'Ellie', 'Maddie', 'Clidna', 'Tor', 'Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Olivia', 'Sam', 'Lynn',]
    surname = [' Dyde', ' Davis', ' Pennington', ' Kelly', ' Hadfield', ' Millward', ' Bennet', ' Goldrick', ' Webb', ' West', ' Cotton', ' Pie', ' Rasberry', ' Fujitsu', ' Neil', ' Gothem',]
    score1 = randint(1, 10)
    score2 = randint(1, 10)
    score3 = randint(1, 10)
    average1 = (score1 + score2 + score3)/3
    score1 = str(score1)
    score2 = str(score2)
    score3 = str(score3)
    average1 = round(average1)
    average1 = str(average1)
    print (('Name: ')+(random.choice(name))+(random.choice(surname)))
    print (('Class: 5B'))
    print (('Score1: ')+(score1))
    print (('Score2: ')+(score2))
    print (('Score3: ')+(score3))
    print (('Average Score: ')+(average1))
    print ('------------------------------------')

print('''

-----------------------
      Class 5C
-----------------------


------------------------------------''')
for i in range(10): #Class 5C
    name = ['John', 'David', 'Bob', 'Luke', 'James', 'Kyle', 'Sam', 'Adam', 'Rick', 'Charlie', 'Alan', 'George', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Batman', 'Oliver', 'Rebeca', 'Emily', 'Amy', 'Nat', 'Ellie', 'Maddie', 'Clidna', 'Tor', 'Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Olivia', 'Sam', 'Lynn',]
    surname = [' Dyde', ' Davis', ' Pennington', ' Kelly', ' Hadfield', ' Millward', ' Bennet', ' Goldrick', ' Webb', ' West', ' Cotton', ' Pie', ' Rasberry', ' Fujitsu', ' Neil', ' Gothem',]
    score1 = randint(1, 10)
    score2 = randint(1, 10)
    score3 = randint(1, 10)
    average1 = (score1 + score2 + score3)/3
    score1 = str(score1)
    score2 = str(score2)
    score3 = str(score3)
    average1 = round(average1)
    average1 = str(average1)
    print (('Name: ')+(random.choice(name))+(random.choice(surname)))
    print (('Class: 5C'))
    print (('Score1: ')+(score1))
    print (('Score2: ')+(score2))
    print (('Score3: ')+(score3))
    print (('Average Score: ')+(average1))
    print ('------------------------------------')
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create it in alphabetical order; create it, then sort it.

More specifically: put your randomly-generated names in a list, and use either the `sort` method to sort that list, or (as @gefei suggests) use the `sorted` function to get a sorted copy of the list.

Comment: How would you suggest that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the .sort() function? This will sort the list in place if you use it such as:

```
name.sort()
```

Which will sort name to

```
['Adam', 'Alan', 'Alex', 'Amy', 'Batman', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Clidna', 'David', 'Ellie', 'Emily', 'George', 'Hannah', 'James', 'Jimmy', 'John', 'Kyle', 'Lucy', 'Luke', 'Lynn', 'Maddie', 'Nat', 'Oliver', 'Olivia', 'Rebeca', 'Rick', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Tor']
```

This will order your names in but from having a look at your code you also want to display the names in order to the user of the program, no?

If this is the case I would suggest that you restructure your code in the following way:

```
...
name = ['John', 'David', 'Bob', 'Luke', 'James', 'Kyle', 'Sam', 'Adam', 'Rick', 'Charlie', 'Alan', 'George', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Batman', 'Oliver', 'Rebeca', 'Emily', 'Amy', 'Nat', 'Ellie', 'Maddie', 'Clidna', 'Tor', 'Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Olivia', 'Sam', 'Lynn',]
surname = [' Dyde', ' Davis', ' Pennington', ' Kelly', ' Hadfield', ' Millward', ' Bennet', ' Goldrick', ' Webb', ' West', ' Cotton', ' Pie', ' Rasberry', ' Fujitsu', ' Neil', ' Gothem',]
names = []
for i in range(10):
    names.append(random.choice(name)+random.choice(surname))
names.sort()
print names
```

Not entirely sure this works out perfectly, just copy pasted most of your code  but I hope you get the gist of it.

What this is meant to achieve is to create a list of all names and then sort them, keep in mind that this does not save generated names between different runs of the program (I presume this is not necessary).

The reason I suggest this is that no matter how you organize the lists you have with name candidates you do at this line pick random names from that list:

```
print (('Name: ')+(random.choice(name))+(random.choice(surname)))
```

Hence why I choose to create a random list with 10 names first and then sort it.

Comment: Yeah i tried this but instead of putting the words in order it took out letters individual and printed them in order for the names: [' ', 'C', 'P', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'i', 'l', 'n'] That is actually what the code posted for the people's name.

Comment: Ah, I see, try using names.append(random.choice(name))+random.choice(surname)) instead of +=

Comment: Yeah i tried that as well, i tried it and it came up with a syntex error if i used 2 brackets at the end of (surname)). I tried it with 1 bracket and it cam up with a error saying:  names.append(random.choice(name))+random.choice(surname) TypeError: unsporting operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: I have updated my example with what I mean, this time I ran the code instead of just typing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Making the idea of Scott more concrete:

```
>>> name = ['John', 'David', 'Bob', 'Luke', 'James', 'Kyle', 'Sam', 'Adam', 'Rick', 'Charlie', 'Alan', 'George', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Batman', 'Oliver', 'Rebeca', 'Emily', 'Amy', 'Nat', 'Ellie', 'Maddie', 'Clidna', 'Tor', 'Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Olivia', 'Sam', 'Lynn',]
>>> sorted(name)
['Adam', 'Alan', 'Alex', 'Amy', 'Batman', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Clidna', 'David', 'Ellie', 'Emily', 'George', 'Hannah', 'James', 'Jimmy', 'John', 'Kyle', 'Lucy', 'Luke', 'Lynn', 'Maddie', 'Nat', 'Oliver', 'Olivia', 'Rebeca', 'Rick', 'Sam', 'Sam', 'Tor']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you would like to accumulate the results for *all* classes sorted by name, generate your data and store it in a list. Then sort and print the list:

```
results = []
for i in range(10): #Class 5A
    name = ['John', 'David', 'Bob', 'Luke', 'James', 'Kyle', 'Sam', 'Adam', 'Rick', 'Charlie', 'Alan', 'George', 'Alex', 'Jimmy', 'Batman', 'Oliver', 'Rebeca', 'Emily', 'Amy', 'Nat', 'Ellie', 'Maddie', 'Clidna', 'Tor', 'Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Olivia', 'Sam', 'Lynn',]
    surname = [' Dyde', ' Davis', ' Pennington', ' Kelly', ' Hadfield', ' Millward', ' Bennet', ' Goldrick', ' Webb', ' West', ' Cotton', ' Pie', ' Rasberry', ' Fujitsu', ' Neil', ' Gothem',]
    scores = [randint(1, 10) for _ in range(3)]
    average = round(sum(scores) / 3.0)
    results.append((random.choice(name), random.choice(surname), '5A', scores, average))
```

Ditto for the other classes. Now sort and print. Note that the sort will be based primarily on the first item of the tuples in the list, which is first name in this case. You can change the key via the sort function (see `key` argument), or you could add surname to the tuple before first name.

```
results.sort()
for r in results:
    print('Name: {} {}'.format(r[0], r[1]))
    print('Class: {}'.format(r[2]))
    for i, score in enumerate(r[3], 1):
        print('Score{}: {}'.format(i, score))
    print('Average Score: {}'.format(r[4]))
    print('------------------------------------')
```

If you wanted individual sorted results per class, just reset the `results` list to an empty list before each class and print the results at the end of each class.

Answer (score 0):

Further from what Scott has said. Create the list, then iterate over it.

Outside the loop:

```
names_list = [random.choice(surname) + ", " + (random.choice(name)) for x in range(1,10)]
print sorted(names_list)
```

Then instead of `print (('Name: ')+(random.choice(name))+(random.choice(surname)))`, we have

```
print 'Name: ' + sorted(names_list)[i]
```